# How to validate negative string number

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm currently doing a C# WPf application. 
May i know how to validate for the string value? Example "0.00" or "-1.00",etc?

Because both of them is return as a string that i retrieve from SAP, is there anyway to check?

Sorry I'm still new to C# , not really familiar with the function that have in the C#.

Comment: Validate it based on what rules? What aspect do you want validated?

Comment: negative string means? do you want to check the content is a number and wether its negative?

Comment: Have a look at `decimal.Parse` and `decimal.TryParse`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Actually i was trying to check for current balance left, if the SAP return me positive balance then i proceed, if it return negative value then i stop the process. Example "Current Balance : 10.00" then proceed , else if "Current Balance: -15.00" then exit program

Comment: Dending where you do it, it looks like floating numbers, so you could try do to Double.TryParse("the string",out doubleVariable) it returns a booleans if it is a double or not

Comment: @MarcusTan If thats the Case i would look into regualar expression, because the value is mixed with characters

Comment: Anyway, I'm not checking whether the string is number or not. What i wanted to check is whether the string that return is negative value or not. Please don't simply mark this is duplicate or what...

Comment: You may check the result from `decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out temp_decimal)`. InvariantCulture is necessary if your string is always point sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to check if the number that you get back is a negative number?

```
double number = 0;
if(double.TryParse(myString,out number)){
   if (number > 0)
       \\Do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to check the number whether i get is negative number or not. Unlike those simply mark the question withoutht understand the question asked.

Let me try it out firsts. thanks for your answer

Comment: and for your correction it was if(double.TryParse(myString,out number))

Answer (score 0):

you can use TryParse() as bellow

```
    string s="0.00";
    double dvalue=0;
    if(!double.TryParse(s,out dvalue)){
       //not valid
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have a double value?
Try

```
Double.Parse(...)
```

edit: corrected method

Comment: Again, that's Java, not C#...

Comment: My fault. Corrected.